# Mini bot animation using armatures and constraints

Tags: animation, armature, constraints

I am attempting an animation, a small bot like motion.

[image: Attempted animation]

This is only one half of the animation and a bit more of the other half cycle.

The current animation is done using only one armature and couple of constraints. I was able to animate the first half by just rotating the  armature. The rest is manually keyed for reference.

The current setup is depicted below:

[image: Outliner]

[image: Setup]

As an end goal, I would like to create an endless loop over curve paths.

Unfortunately, I am unable to arrive at a symmetric arrangement of armatures and constraints as they end up locking each other. In an ideal setup, I would assume that just rotating the armatures would suffice.

Kindly help me out with a setup that could work.